# Run DOS program from R

Tags: r

So this command line runs fine in DOS, and the path to npx is in the path variable

`npx @squoosh/cli --mozjpeg {quality:75} test.PNG`

But I want to call it from R

This doesn't work:

`system("npx @squoosh/cli --mozjpeg {quality:75} test.PNG")`
It just returns "127"

Nor does this:

`shell("npx @squoosh/cli --mozjpeg {quality:75} test.PNG")`
Returns "'npx' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Maybe you have to put the whole path to the commands

Comment: probably `npx` is not on your path. `shell(" C:\directory_path_to_npx\npx.exe' @squoosh/cli --mozjpeg {quality:75} test.PNG")` or adding `npx` to your path will fix it.

Comment: Not a big fan of this syntax, if you have to work Windows, I suggest cygwin.

Comment: It doesn't like the backslashes:  shell(" C:\program files\nodejs\npx.cmd' @squoosh/cli --mozjpeg {quality:75} test.PNG")  But  npx is already in my path.

Comment: The R commands in the question work for me without any changes.  Make sure that `test.png` is in the current directory.  In R,  `getwd()` and `setwd("path")` can be used to get and set the directory path.  Also remove any existing `test.jpg` so you can be sure any such file was just created.

Answer (score 1):

Try `system2` instead, it's the recommended way for system calls.

```
txt <- "npx @squoosh/cli --mozjpeg {quality:75} test.PNG"
txt <- scan(text = txt, what = character())
cmd <- txt[1]
args <- txt[-1]
system2(cmd, args)
```

Or simply

```
system2(command = txt[1], args = txt[-1])
```